# Problems with intent in second activity

Tags: java, android

I am new in the android dev and java 
My idea is to make BMI that will have history.
So I am at the point where I struggle with the intent for the second activity.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openActivity2();
        }
    });
}

private void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am getting:

> can not resolve symbol intent

Comment: please post the full error log

Comment: Have you imported the intent class?

Comment: Did you build your project?

Comment: @JakeB i have it

Comment: @Abhimanyu Yup i have

Comment: Typo: Intent class must begin with capital letter

Comment: @Abhimanyu TY!!!

Answer (score 1):

'i' should capital when you create new Intent() object The openActivity2() should look like this

```
        private void openActivity2() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
```